# Using Recipient List Router to route to JMS Queues

Tags: routes, spring-integration

Can I use a recipient list router to route to 2 JMS Queues from an HTTP Inbound Endpoint? My goal is to route  messages from the HTTP Inbound Endpoint to 2 jms queues i.e. orders and items queue.  I want to use the recipient list router to do it.  I don't want to use the pub sub channel solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
    xmlns:int-jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd">



    <import resource="queue-config.xml" />


    <int:channel id="productChannel"/>

    <int:channel id="jmsIn1">
         <int:queue/>
    </int:channel>

    <int:channel id="jmsIn2">
       <int:queue/>
    </int:channel>


    <!-- Want the orders from this endpoint to be placed in queues-->
    <!-- Doesn't work even without <queue/> -->
    <int-http:inbound-gateway supported-methods="PUT,POST"
        path="/products/order" request-channel="productChannel">
    </int-http:inbound-gateway>



    <int:chain input-channel="productChannel">
        <int:recipient-list-router id="jmsRouter">
            <int:recipient channel="jmsIn1" />
            <int:recipient channel="jmsIn2" />
       </int:recipient-list-router>

        <int:service-activator ref="orderHandler"
                 method="addOrder"/>
    </int:chain>



    <bean id="orderHandler" class="com.jms.OrderHandler" />


    <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="product.outbound.channel"
        channel="jmsIn1" destination="orders.queue" />

    <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="records.outbound.channel"
        channel="jmsIn2" destination="items.queue" />



</beans>
```

Comment: I tried using a recipient list using jms outbound adapter, but I get the following exceptionorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
h name 'org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#0': Invocati
on of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
: All handlers except for the last one in the chain must implement the MessagePr
oducer interface. Object of class [org.springframework.integration.router.Recipi
entListRouter] must be an instance of interface org.springframework.integration.
core.MessageProducer

Comment: The goal: Save the messages coming into an HTTP Endpoint directly into 2 JMS Queues before processing the messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest your issue isn't clear.

The `<recipient-list-router>` exactly **does** that.

You specify several `<recipient>` and each of them will receiver the same message. And it doesn't matter if it will be JMS Adapters or anything else.

Reading your question you can do the same even just with `<publish-subscribe-channel>`: you need to specify several `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>` with the same `channel` reference.

**UPDATE**

You really had to start from the logs and your misconfiguration...

So, let's take a look to the StackTrace one more time!

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit h name 'org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#0': Invocati on of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : All handlers except for the last one in the chain must implement the MessagePr oducer interface. Object of class [org.springframework.integration.router.RecipientListRouter] must be an instance of interface org.springframework.integration. core.MessageProducer
```

So, it says that your `RecipientListRouter` must be `MessageProducer` to shift a message to the next handler in the `<chain>` or it must be as the last component in the `<chain>`.

According to the `Router` architecture it isn't `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler`, like `ServiceActivatingHandler`, for example.

Having multi choice on the router config, it is logical that we just don't have there the normal reply behavior.

So, to kick your task you just should move one more handler to your `<recipient-list-router>` mapping!

Comment: I have added more clarity and some code. Sorry, if it wasn't clear. I don't want to use the <publish-subscribe-channel> .

Comment: See an update in my answer. Please, be more informative the next time.

Comment: I did figure out the reason from the stacktrace what the problem was.  however, my understanding was that i would have to provide a class which extends MessageProducerSupport to the recipient-list-router which I thought would be too much work. I had it working  using a service-activator with an autowired jmstemplate and also using the <publish-subscribe-channel> but my preference was to use the recipient-list-router.  So from your answer my understanding is that this cannot be done?. Thank you

Comment: You replied "So, to kick your task you just should move one more handler to your <recipient-list-router> mapping! " what does that mean?